# Is it a security risk if contact record id is exposed in URL

Tags: security

Could you please let us know whether it is a security issue if contact record ID is exposed in URL ? What is the best way to avoid exposing the record ID in Custom community URL ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation. 
For example, if a guest user (during self-registration) can brute-force contact ID and your controller returns some sensitive information from this record (email, phone, etc.), it's unsafe.  Alternatively, you can create a custom object that will store JSON data and check user access to the data. Pass this hash to the URL instead of the contact ID and perform all calculations on the server side. 
For internal users, you should configure sharings to avoid unauthorized access.

(We are now talking about guest user. If user authorised we use sharings)
This mechanism can be implemented in different ways. I’ll better show you possible scenario with possible solution.
Let’s imagine that in your community, users can send invitations to not-registered users to register in your community. We create a contact, fill out the information (email, phone, name), and send this user a URL that looks something like this: 
https://yourDomain/selfRegistration?type=invitation&contactId=0037Y00001dgj0bQAA 
 When a user clicks on this URL from an email, he is redirected to the LWC self-registration page with the contractId parameter, and the controller retrieves the completed information (email, mobile) for a better user experience. However, any unauthorised user (guest profile) can brute force the contractId and retrieve sensitive or personal information from the contact (if this is discovered by a hacker, your reputation will be ruined). 
My approach 
Let's create a custom object that will store JSON data containing necessary information (in this case, contactId). Also, let’s create some custom fields that will store which profiles, users, or emails have access to this data (in our scenario, profile  = GuestUser). Let’s edit our link a little bit.
 
https://yourDomain/selfRegistration?hash=ygherigh8743hg8734gh8723fh3287hg843
 
Now, when we are redirected to the self-registration, we should check access to this hash (in our situation, any user with a Guset Profile can access it). 
Does the user have the required profile? 
Does the user have the required userId? 
Does the user have the required email? 
And so on, whatever you can think of. 
We SOQL contact information (email, phone) and display it on the registration form if the user has access.
It's impossible to brute force a hash with 100 characters, for example. It would not be bruteforce, it would be a DDOS.

Comment: thank you for the response . Is there any other mechanism ? Also in above mentioned mechanism, what data will be stored in custom object ?

Comment: @Hemant-2 I updated my answer. There are a huge number of ways to implement this logic.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, ID values in the URL are perfectly safe, provided you have configured your security settings correctly. It is up to the Administrators for an org to make sure that the security settings are correct, and you can also test it out for yourself to ensure that the data is correctly secured by using various logins.

Comment: Using security tool, we were able to retrieve, manipulate with different record ID and could do different operations with manipulated record id, so it is security violation . Could you please let me know what is the best way to encrypt the id param in URL and decode it in target page / controller ( targer get can be - same page / controller or different page / controller)  and use it in logic, so functionality is not broken

Comment: @Hemant-2 I don't have enough information to help you further at this time. As I said, if your security settings are appropriate, what you're describing won't be possible for a normal user. As to what you can do about encrypting the ID, that depends on the scenario. Standard pages and standard controllers need an unencrypted ID. Custom controllers can use the Crypto class to encrypt/decrypt any kind of strings, including Id values, but you'll have to implement it everywhere.